# Did I prove this limit correctly?

Tags: limits

Given $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$ and  $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = M$ implies that  $\lim_{n \to \infty}2a_n + 3b_n = 2L + 3M$

> *Proof*
>
> > Assume $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = L$ and  $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = M$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we have $\frac{\epsilon}{4}>0$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{6}>0$
> >
> > $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$    when $n > N_1$
> >
> > $|b_n - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{6}$    when $n > N_2$
> >
> > Set $n>N= \max \left \{ N_1, N_2 \right \}$,we have
> >
> > $|2a_n + 3b_n - (2L + 3M)| \leq |2a_n - 2L| + |3b_n - 3M| = |2||a_n - L| + |3||b_n - M| < 2\frac{\epsilon}{4} + 3\frac{\epsilon}{6} = \epsilon$

**Question**: I had to work backwards to choose my $\epsilon$, is that a "general" strategy? I omitted my work for finding my $\epsilon$

Comment: Perfect, almost too much so. You worked too hard in working backwards. I would have picked $\frac{\epsilon}{100}$ for both, then we get $\le \frac{2\epsilon}{100}+\frac{3\epsilon}{100}=\frac{5\epsilon}{100}\lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks correct. Working backwards to choose $\epsilon$ is also the strategy I'd recommend in general.

Comment: But I've noticed that in my proof class that if we "include" the work of working backwards (with step-by-step explanation) then it is considered informal

Comment: @jak It usually isn't included, but I wouldn't say it makes the proof "informal" in the sense I use the word (i.e. the proof is no less technically complete and correct).

Comment: I asked because most books omit that important work. It took me a while to understand this concept. Thank you very much